# Panini + Instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, instafeedjs

Having issues with using the templating aspect of Instafeed due to the fact my site uses [Panini](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html) (Foundation 6).

Instafeed - http://instafeedjs.com

Found this article that solves the issue for Jekyll sites.
http://chrissciolla.com/tech/jekyll-instafeedjs-tutorial.html

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What issue are you having? Are you seeing errors? Please include any relevant code excerpts and a detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly without seeing your code and how you're implementing it, but the problem is almost certainly due to the fact that both Panini and Instafeed use handlebars for templating.  If you're writing your Instafeed template within a page or partial that is being parsed by Panini, it will try to process that handlebars then and there, and it won't be there for Instafeed to use.

The simplest solution would be to move the Instafeed template into a file that Panini is not parsing, for example instead of having your Instafeed instantiation in an inline script in the layout, put it into a separate JS file.  If you're using the either the basic template or the ZURB template from https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html, putting it in app.js should work.